# Significant blocation change event in ios7 - Background service call

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, locationmanager

I am using Significant location services in my app. 
If my app killed by system or force close by user, using event of Significant location change services I am sending location data to my server,in iOS 6.
In iOS6 my app sends data to server after force close also. 
But in iOS 7 I am not getting this significant location change event.

Comment: Be aware that iOS 7 and Xcode 5 are still under NDA, which restricts you from talking about them outside of the official Apple Developers forum. This might be why you will not get any answers for your question.

Answer (score 5):

As iOS 7 SDK is not under NDA anymore, I'm posting the answer here, for the sake of completion. As mentioned in answers here: [Monitoring regions but location icon disappears when app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081570/monitoring-regions-but-location-icon-disappears-when-app-is-killed/19085680#19085680) **iOS 7 does not allow significant location changes in background, if user has killed the application in app switcher**.

More information on [Apple forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/882691#882691), which also contains the following reply from Apple representative:

> If a user swipes up in the app switcher then the OS will not launch
>   the app unless explicitly told to do so by the user.  So no, SLC will
>   not be launching the app, nor will silent notifications.  The only
>   thing that will launch the app at that point is the user tapping the
>   icon.  The intention here is that the user has expressed their choice
>   of not having that app running any more for any reason, so we honor
>   that.  In this situation, there's really nothing that you can do.  The
>   next time the user launches the app you can let them know that some of
>   the data may be missing, although you really cannot tell whether
>   there's missing data or not (i.e. you might have been killed by the OS
>   in the background and the user may not have moved thereby not
>   triggering any SLC notifications).  My suggestion would be to gather
>   the data you can within the policies of the OS and if the user has
>   manually killed the app then respect that wish and don't do anything. 
>   By all means, feel free to file a bug report if this change in
>   behavior winds up causing problems for you or (especially) confusion
>   for your users.

Comment: So, is there no way to get users location when app is killed?

Comment: No. User is the admin of the device.

Comment: I have asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43317108/6536841) please look at it